# Fechar Excel após executar Macro vba no Qlikview

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba, macro

Macro

```
set obj = ActiveDocument.GetSheetObject("CH1")
obj.Export "caminho_para_salvar_arquivo"
```

E agora preciso fechar o Excel, usei o seguinte comando.

```
obj.Close caminho_para_salvar_arquivo'
```

E recebo o erro

```
Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: "obj.Close"
```

Comment: Tenta com este comando: `ActiveWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=True`

Comment: @R.Galamba tbm não funcionou, mas depois de varias tentativa, rolou "obj.Close"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolução do problema:

```
obj.Close
```